# Laravel: Escape "LIKE" clause?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I escape a `LIKE` clause in Laravel/Eloquent? e.g.,

```
$search = Input::query('sSearch', '');
if($search !== '') {
    $paginatedBookings->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
}
```

If `$search` contains a `%` or `_` they need to be escaped.

Comment: Your `$search` variable will always/only contain these two wildcards?

Comment: @RahilWazir: No..? It will contain whatever the user types in. They shouldn't be allowed to search for wildcards. I just want to put a backslash in front of them. It's a one-liner but I was hoping for something database-agnostic.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The other answer forgets about escaping the escape character itself, here is a more robust solution:

```
/**
 * Escape special characters for a LIKE query.
 *
 * @param string $value
 * @param string $char
 *
 * @return string
 */
function escape_like(string $value, string $char = '\\'): string
{
    return str_replace(
        [$char, '%', '_'],
        [$char.$char, $char.'%', $char.'_'],
        $value
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution:

```
$search = Input::query('sSearch', '');
if($search !== '') {
    $escSearch = Util::escapeLike($search);
    $paginatedBookings->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $escSearch . '%');
    $paginatedBookings->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $escSearch . '%');
}

class Util {
    public static function escapeLike($str) {
        return str_replace(['\\', '%', '_'], ['\\\\', '\%', '\_'], $str);
    }
}
```

[reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

I was hoping for something database-agnostic and more robust. I think you can change the escape char in MySQL, although I don't know why you would.

Comment: @RahilWazir Double slashes aren't necessary when used in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs especially when we want to query on a polymorphic related table.As an example, I wanted to find a column value named `App\Example\Files` by querying with `like`. But it failed because of the backslash.

While testing, I found that we need "4 backslashes" for the Laravel side and for the mysql side. For the query to work properly.

I also verified this with the toSql () method. As a result, the output of the mysql query was like this and it worked:

```
select `file` from `examples` where file like '%App\\\\Example\\\\Files%'
```

I wrote a little helper function to do the backslash correction

**before:**

```
  DB::table('examples')
    ->select('file')
    ->whereRaw("state like '%App\Example\Files%'")
    ->toSql();
```

**incorrect output:**

```
select `file` from `examples` where file like '%App\Example\Files%'
```

**after**

```
function handle_backslash($value) :string {
    return str_replace('\\', '\\\\\\\\', $value);
}

DB::table('examples')
    ->select('file')
    ->whereRaw("file like '%" . handle_backslash('App\Example\Files') . "%'")
    ->toSql();
```

**correct output:**

```
select `file` from `examples` where file like '%App\\\\Example\\\\Files%'
```

Comment: It's not just the backslashes that need to be escaped. Please check out the accepted answer. If your value contains `%` or `_` you will also have problems.

Comment: @mpen you are right, while still you can update the helper function to assign new properties for this purpose and you can use this for the expression that you mentioned.