# Laravel-5 'LIKE' equivalent (Eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm using the below code to pull some results from the database with Laravel 5.

```
BookingDates::where('email', Input::get('email'))->orWhere('name', 'like', Input::get('name'))->get()
```

However, the orWhereLike doesn't seem to be matching any results.  What does that code produce in terms of MySQL statements?

I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

```
select * from booking_dates where email='my@email.com' or name like '%John%'
```

Answer (score 507, accepted):

If you want to see what is run in the database use `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` to see what queries were run.

Try this

```
BookingDates::where('email', Input::get('email'))
    ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . Input::get('name') . '%')->get();
```

Comment: is this query sql injection protected?

Comment: @partho Yes. Laravel screens the whole string that you pass as the third argument of the `where` method.

Comment: While injection protected you might want to check for unexpected % in user input. E.g., LIKE "%John%" and LIKE "John%" perform differently (you might only intend the latter). Also consider empty input, and then of "%" alone, which also might lead to unintended results from the above code.

Comment: Agreed with Ian. Laravel only does partial escaping. There's still a lot of mischief possible if you don't properly escape the LIKE. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42028380/329062

Comment: I added `preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $search);` because I don't need special chars, and it protects it from `%` injection too

Answer (score 34):

I have scopes for this, hope it help somebody.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#local-scopes

```
public function scopeWhereLike($query, $column, $value)
{
    return $query->where($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
}

public function scopeOrWhereLike($query, $column, $value)
{
    return $query->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
}
```

Usage:

```
$result = BookingDates::whereLike('email', $email)->orWhereLike('name', $name)->get();
```

Answer (score 20):

```
$data = DB::table('borrowers')
        ->join('loans', 'borrowers.id', '=', 'loans.borrower_id')
        ->select('borrowers.*', 'loans.*')   
        ->where('loan_officers', 'like', '%' . $officerId . '%')
        ->where('loans.maturity_date', '<', date("Y-m-d"))
        ->get();
```

Comment: ->where('loan_officers', 'like', '%' . $officerId . '%')  where loan_officers is the serialized field

Answer (score 17):

I think this is better, following the good practices of passing parameters to the query:

```
BookingDates::whereRaw('email = ? or name like ?', [$request->email,"%{$request->name}%"])->get();
```

Better:

```
BookingDates::where('email',$request->email)
    ->orWhere('name','like',"%{$request->name}%")->get();
```

[You can see it in the documentation, Laravel 5.5.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)

> You can also use the Laravel scout and make it easier with search.
> [Here is the documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout#installation)

Comment: Raw is **never** better. You should sacrifice functionality if it requires `raw` to achieve it, or approach it differently.

Answer (score 10):

the query which is mentioned below worked for me maybe it will be helpful for someone.

```
 $platform = DB::table('idgbPlatforms')->where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$requestedplatform}%")->first();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to use it on controller you can do something like:

$generatequery = 'select * from blogs where is_active = 1 and blog_name like '%'.$blogs.'%' order by updated_at desc, id desc';

$blogslists = DB::select($generatequery);

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Postgres, The key word **ILIKE** can be used instead of **LIKE** to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

this worked for me.

```
User::where('name, 'ILIKE', $search)->get();
```

[postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)

Comment: I do not get the connection between `What does that code produce in terms of [SQL] statements?` and above reply - what question does this answer?

Comment: then using this isn't safe

Comment: LIKE is case-insensitive, what collation are you using for it to not be insensitive, definitely not utf8mb4...

Comment: @zanderwar WRONG !!! - in Postgresql LIKE is case-sensitive and you **have to** use ILIKE to make it case-insensitive. 

_The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension._
[docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)