# How can I find whole words only in a LIKE query Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I find whole words in a LIKE query in Laravel's Eloquent?

For example, if someone searched SA the following results can come up with LIKE %sa%:

- My name is Sam
- I live in SA

But I need a search that only returns:

- I live in SA

How can I accomplish this while at the same time preventing SQL injections? I'm quite cautious with a raw query due to this - unless any alternatives are offered?

Thank you.

Comment: remove % from query you will get only SA

Comment: Use `=` to perform an exact match, `LIKE` is for matching patterns.

Comment: if you are using eloquent, then you don't need to worry about sql injections

Comment: if SA is a single word in a text you can use `RLIKE` with word boundaries.

Comment: `DB::select('*')->where('place','=', 'SA');`

Comment: Sorry - let me clarify in my question. Edited Search Terms - i need a broad search within text, not a direct match.

Comment: [Please, see the question, Hope this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761950/laravel-5-like-equivalent-eloquent)

Comment: You can try `LIKE BINARY %SA%`

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use `REGEXP` (`RLIKE`), which would result to something like this:

```
$place = 'sa';
$res = DB::select( DB::raw("select * from my_table where place REGEXP '[[:<:]]$place[[:>:]]'") );
```

But this creates a vector for attack via SQL Injection, so in order to sanitize the query we can do the following:

```
$place = 'sa';
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("select * from my_table where place REGEXP '[[:<:]]:place[[:>:]]'"), array(
   'place' => $place,
));
```

`select()` accepts bindings, you can check it [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L262) :)

### Edit

Here's the signature of `select`

```
public function select($query, $bindings = [], $useReadPdo = true)
```