# Not able to get complete query with like condition Laravel 6.5.2

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I'm building a website using Laravel Framework 6.5.2.
But I have a problem with Query Builder.
I tried 'where like' condition but it does not work.

```
$query = Order::where('customer_name', 'LIKE', '%Jone%');
print_r($query->toSql());
// this returns "select * from orders where customer_name LIKE ?"
```

Why does this happen? And how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel-5 'LIKE' equivalent (Eloquent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761950/laravel-5-like-equivalent-eloquent)

Answer (score 2):

please Try this

You miss `get();`

```
$term = "Jone";
$query = Order::where('customer_name', '%' . $term . '%')->get();
```

or

```
$query = Order::where('customer_name', '%' . Input::get('name') . '%')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. In fact, this method is what I tried first. But because it does not work, I tried the upper one.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: $query = Order::where('customer_name', 'LIKE', '%Jone%')->get();    print_r($query);

Comment: its work for you? get method?

Comment: yes, thank you. without get() method, the $query->toSqI() function doesn't return complete sql.

Comment: please select this answer.If its help..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that there is actually anything wrong here.  To understand why, consider that prepared statements (which is what Laravel uses under the hood) are not actually evaluated in your application code.  Rather, the statement with the binding parameters are sent to the MySQL database and evaluated there.  So, rightfully your prepared statement should look like this:

```
select * from orders where customer_name like ?
```

Now, as to whether your query be logically correct, or if there be any other problems, is another question, but nothing you did show us looks wrong per se.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses Prepared Statements. They're a way of writing an SQL statement without dropping variables directly into the SQL string. The `?` you see are placeholders or bindings for the information which will later be substituted and automatically sanitized by PDO. See the PHP docs for more information on prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

To view the data that will be substituted into the query string you can call the `getBindings()` function on the query as below.

```
$query = Order::where('customer_name', 'LIKE', '%Jone%');

dd($query->toSql(), $query->getBindings());
```

The array of bindings gets substituted in the same order the `?` appears in the SQL statement.

Or another way to get binding data is.

```
\DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log

$query = Order::where('customer_name', 'LIKE', '%Jone%')->get();

dd(\DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log
```