# Laravel - where like function is not working in some cases

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm new to Laravel 6 and I have a question regarding the where() function.

I have a User model and a article model, in my user model I have setup the relationship as hasMany(App\Article::class), which means an user can have many articles. Let's assume that user 1 has a few articles with titled "How to..." tutorials.

In the tinker, if I do:

```
$user->articles()->where('title', 'like', '%how to%')->get();
```

it shows all the titles that has the wordings "how to", however if I do:

```
$user->articles->where('title', 'like', '%how to%'); //but $user->articles->where('id', 2); works perfectly
```

It returns blank result. Why?

Comment: One to many and many to many relations return array of collections and needs to use parentheses. one to one relation do not need.

Comment: `$user->articles` is a `Collection`, `$user->articles()` is a `Builder`, they both have a `where()` method, but they function differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because your first where() `$user->articles()->where('title', 'like', '%how to%')->get();` builds an SQL Query (QueryBuilder https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries).

Your second where() tries to get a value out of an one to one relationship. If you want to get a value from an many to many relation you need the parantheses – you have to use the function `$user->articles()`.

Answer (score -2):

Because you didn't specify the `->get()` method

In order to retrieve data, you should give 1 of these method
    `->first()`,
    `->last()`,
`->find()`

The `->all()` method is used when you don't want to restrict any condition to the model.

If it's not working, see the link [Laravel-5 'LIKE' equivalent (Eloquent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761950/laravel-5-like-equivalent-eloquent)