# search filter is not fetching data until clicking on search button

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

It's a laravel vuejs project. Here is the photo of my product page :
[image]

Products were supposed to display at that page, but it's completely null until I am clicking on the search button . After clicking on the search button, the page loads the products and the search option working as well.

[image]

My codes are :

web.php ->

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Mastercontroller@index');

Route::get('/search', 'App\Http\Controllers\Mastercontroller@search');

Route::any('{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Mastercontroller@index');
```

Mastercontroller.php ->

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\myproductcase;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Mastercontroller extends Controller
{
     public function index(){
        return view('welcome');
     }

     public function search(Request $r){
    
        $search = $r->get('q');
        return myproductcase::where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
     }
 }
```

productpage ->

```
   <template>
   <div>

   <div class="search"><input v-model="search" type=text></input><button 
   @click.prevent="makesearch()">Search</button></div>
     
     <div class="product-list">
        <div v-if="showsearch==true"> 
             <div v-for="getresult in getdata" v-bind:key="getresult.id">
                    <div class="product">
                    <h1>{{getresult.name}}</h1>
                    <h3>{{getresult.price}}</h3>
                    <p>{{getresult.description}}</p>
             </div>    
        </div> 
        <div v-if="showsearch==false">
            no data found
            </div>    
         </div>               
      </div>
    </div>  
</template>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return{
        search : '',
        showsearch : false,
        getdata : []
     }
   },
   methods : {
       async makesearch(){
            fetch('/search?q='+this.search).then(hi=>hi.json()).then(hi=>{
                    console.log();
                    this.getdata = hi;
                    this.search = '';
                    this.showsearch = true;
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }   
        
       },
   
   }
</script>
```

Comment: The question is, product is not loading before i am clicking on the search button , I want products should be displayed automatically , search option should work like a filter

Comment: (1) do you want to perform search as soon as page loads? (2) on typing in textbox, want to perform search and display data without clicking on search button?

Comment: if you want to try (2) as specified by @NileshPatel try using watch

Comment: @nilesh patel @ bhucho no brother, I was trying to get all products displayed as soon as the page loads.  I got the solution though - thanks for your time and thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you load the page for the first time, there is not get query parameter in your url, so in the line

```
$search = $r->get('q'); // Is equal to NULL
```

The query that you are doing the first time is:

```
return myproductcase::where('name','LIKE','%NULL%')->get();
```

You could use the syntax below for setting up a default parameter

```
$search = $r->get('q', 'default value' );
```

PD: Be careful with SQL Injection [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761950/laravel-5-like-equivalent-eloquent#comment77491426_30762205)

Edit:
Also in your Component call in your **mounted** method the **makesearch** method.

```
data(){
    ...
}

...

mounted(){
   this.makesearch()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I got another solution though , using created() to load all data for the first time - is this a bad practice ?

Comment: I Have edited my answer, I always use the mounted method. Make a research about component lifecycle in Vue.

Comment: @Shishir if you have lesser data, its fine to load in mounted() but if you have huge set of data, not a good approach. In thqt case let user search specific data.

Comment: you mean, I should not put all data in single page ?

Comment: Adding pagination would solve the problem of charging huge amount of data