# Take a word from a sentence in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```
$text="Samsung Galaxy s21 ";
$product=  Product::Select('*')->where('name', 'like', "%{$text}%")->get();
```

how can i get `Galaxy`  related products  form `$product`

Comment: the question is, how are you gonna extract `galaxy` from that string. Is it following any rule ? if the results give products related to all parts of the string (`Samsung`, `galaxy` and `s21`) is it still correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$product= Product::where('name', 'like', '%' . $text . '%')->get();
```

Or

```
$product= Product::where('name', 'like', "%$text%")->get();
```

You can do it like this. Got it from this thread,
[Laravel-5 'LIKE' equivalent (Eloquent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761950/laravel-5-like-equivalent-eloquent)